# Estimating the number of Twitter users that drive to work

Tags: estimation

How would I go about estimating the number of active Twitter users that drive to work each morning worldwide?

What data would I need to know, and how would I approach this problem using those data points?

Comment: This may be better suited to statistics.SE.

Comment: Hello katelyn, this sounds like an interview estimation question to me, like "how many drycleaners are there in New York?" or "What is the total amount of rent paid by New Yorkers in January 2013?"

Comment: That may be what it sounds like, but I'm actually looking to find the stats to see how big of a market there would be for users who would like their tweets read to them during their morning commute.

Answer (score 1):

How good an estimate do you need?  The number of active Twitter users (for some definition of active) must be available from Twitter or online news articles.  What fraction drive to work?  Certainly not more than $100\%.$  Probably more than $10\%$  Now we are within a factor $3.$  Sounds flip, but maybe it is good enough.  What later estimates are you going to make (uptake rate of a product?  That won't be this good)  To do better, there must be data online about fractions of country populations that drive to work.  Twitter people might be somewhat more or less prone to drive to work, but that will get you closer if you can get the Twitter distribution by country.  I would guess that would get you to $\pm 30-50\%$.  To do better you might have to pay for a survey. Maybe that still wouldn't be better, but maybe it is more impressive.

Comment: right, so twitter distribution by country, as well as the # of those users that are actually active. Then the fraction of that population that drive to work? Perhaps working class people are more likely to drive to work, and are more likely to use twitter.

Comment: katelyn friedson - Can you say a little about what you've tried so far?  @Ross Millikan - I don't see how you get "a factor [of] 3" for 10% compared to 100%.  Also, does "±30−50%" mean "about 30-50%"?

Comment: @rolando2:  If I guess 30%, I can only be off (about) a factor of 3 either way.  And yes, I meant $\pm 30-50\%$ as that you would have an uncertainty of about that much.  I think better accuracy is hard to come by, and probably not worth the effort as there will be larger uncertainties to come.